# How can I register an interface that inherits from an interface in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

Say I have an interface that inherits another interface:

```
public interface IInvoiceFactory : IConfigFactory<Invoice, InvoiceRequest>
```

This doesn't resolve:

```
container.RegisterType<IConfigFactory<Invoice, InvoiceRequest>, IInvoiceFactory>();
container.RegisterType<IInvoiceFactory, InvoiceFactory>();
```

Is it possible to have an interface inherit another interface in the DI world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this, which isn't quite what you wanted, but may resolve what you need:

```
container.RegisterType<IInvoiceFactory, InvoiceFactory>();
container.RegisterType<IConfigFactory<Invoice, InvoiceRequest>, InvoiceFactory>();
```

That will mean both of these will resolve an instance of `InvoiceFactory`:

```
var factory = container.Resolve<IInvoiceFactory>();
var factory = container.Resolve<IConfigFactory<Invoice, InvoiceRequest>>();
```

Other containers give you ways of registering all interfaces implemented by a type, and I'm guessing Unity provides that mechanism, too, so there is likely a better way of doing this.  As I said though, it depends if this solves your situation or not.

Comment: Yep, I can save a few lines of code and abstract out a bit of complexity by getting away from your answer, which is what I've actually been using up until my idea today ;)  If I don't get a good answer, I suppose I'll write it off as impossible in Unity (maybe not other DI containers) and go back to the old way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I've addressed the issue:

```
container.RegisterType<IConfigFactory<Invoice, InvoiceRequest>, IInvoiceFactory>(
    new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<IInvoiceFactory>()));

container.RegisterType<IInvoiceFactory, InvoiceFactory>();
```

You can also still use NamedRegistration and different `LifetimeManagers` with that solution.